# Approximation of the sum involving binary entropy function

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, it.information-theory, asymptotics, approximation-theory, entropy

Given the following sum:

$S(n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{(1-\operatorname{H}(p))^i}$

where $H$ is the binary entropy function defined as:

$\operatorname{H}(p) = -p\log p - (1-p)\log (1-p) $.

Let $f(n) = \frac{n}{S(n)}$.

Assume $p$ is very small, is it possible to approximate the $S(n)$ and $f(n)$ defined above with simpler closed formulae e.g. a polynomial of $p$ without loosing much precision?

Comment: Is something missing in the sum? As wirtten it is $S(n)=\frac{n}{1-\operatorname{H}(p)}\,$,  $f(n)=1-\operatorname{H}(p)$.

Comment: My apologies, yes, I missed the exponent for $1-H(p)$, just edited my question.

Comment: It's just a geometric series with the largest term at the end. Why don't you just sum it exactly?  Then if you want an approximation for tiny $p$ use a Taylor expansion of the exact sum.

Answer (score 2):

The second order Taylor expansion of $H(p)$ may suffice for you. Expanding $H(p)$ around $p = 1/2$ it is not difficult to show that
$$H(p)=1-\frac{(1-2 p)^2}{2 \ln 2}+O\left(\left(p-\frac{1}{2}\right)^3\right)$$
Thus, using the approximation $1 - H(p) \approx \frac{(1-2 p)^2}{2 \ln 2}$, we get
$$S(n) \approx \sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{2 \ln 2}{(1-2 p)^2}\right)^{i},$$
which is has the simple closed form
$$S(n) \approx \frac{2 \ln 2 \left((1-2 p)^2\right)^{-n} \left(\left((1-2 p)^2\right)^n-(2 \ln 2)^n\right)}{4 p^2-4 p+1-2 \ln 2}.$$

The approximation should be good near $p = 1/2$, however in the numerical examples I have worked out, it seems pretty reasonable.

Comment: I assumed $p$ was very small and maybe very close to $0$, say 1e-2, 1e-3, or 1e-4, will that complicate the approximation?

Comment: Of course. As $p$ approaches 0, the sum approaches $n$ but this approximation doesn't.

Comment: You may want to try the same ideias to obtain a Taylor Series approximation around any point $p$. And you may also calculate the sum in $n$ (geometric progression) and then do Taylor Approximation... some of these thechniques may suffice...

Comment: Oh. This is exactly what Brendan commented above. Sorry dude.

Answer (score 1):

*Almost eight years later*

$$S(n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\Big[1-\operatorname{H}(p)\Big]^i}=\frac{\Big[1-\operatorname{H}(p)\Big]^{-n}-1 }{\operatorname{H}(p) }$$

Answering [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188195/inverse-of-binary-entropy-function-for-0-le-x-le-frac12/4250806?noredirect=1#comment9044400_4250806), I proposed as a rather good approximation for the whole range of $p$
$$\operatorname{H}(p) \sim \big[4p(1-p)\big]^{\frac 34}\implies f(n)=\frac n {S(n)}=\frac{n\operatorname{H}(p) }{\Big[1-\operatorname{H}(p)\Big]^{-n}-1 }$$